# If a window in a plane cabin breaks will a bunch of water vapor form?

Tags: water, pressure

If a plane has some windows broken mid-flight (ie open) will the plane suddenly be full of water vapor because of the difference of pressure?

Comment: i presume this depends on height of flight during which this may occur plus the temperature at this height, yes it is possible, one can use data from meteorology about temperature at various heights and statistics for amount of water and do some calculations that yield at least estimations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Water vapor is invisible. I think you mean fog - fine water droplets condensed from water vapor.

Pressurized planes fly with an 8000 foot equivalent altitude and humidity in the cabin is low. But, at 35,000 feet (called Flight Level 35) it is likely one would get a brief fog. If loss of pressure is fast, you would only get to watch for a few seconds. At those pressures, oxygen actually rapidly diffuses out of the blood in the lungs and unconsciousness comes much sooner than one would expect. There have been plenty of accidents dating back to the WWII fighters that cruised at 40,000 feet where a pilot thought he could manage briefly without his oxygen. Something like this likely happened to the missing Malaysian aircraft.

Comment: ok nice answer, but i would leave the currect status of the [missing aircraft of M. Airlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370), out of this answer. As it stands it is a speculation irrelevant with the answer